# What JSchExceptions are thrown when connection timeout occurs and when file transfer using put is interrupted?

Tags: java, jsch

I am trying to add retry mechanism to my SFTP client which uses JSch. I want to retry sending the file in the following scenarios:

- Connection timeout occurs
- File transfer to remote host using put is interrupted, because of connection issues

What specific `JSchException` messages should I check?

These are the few exceptions I came across (I am not aware of the difference):

- `com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: timeout: socket is not established`
- `com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`

Comment: can you connect outside of java, ssh from the the same machine?

Comment: @MatthiasWiedemann , I don't have a connectivity issue, I am trying to implement exception handling in my code, and would like to know what specific exceptions to catch IF there was a connectivity issue (or upload was interrupted) so that I can re-try.